# document.close() takes very long time to write pdf data to harddisk

Tags: java, performance, pdf, itext

Here is the sample code from itext in action  nup  sample as follows:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
public class NUpTool {
    /** Format of the resulting PDF files. */
    public static final String RESULT = "results/part2/chapter06/result%dup.pdf";
    /**
     * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     * @param src the original PDF
     * @param dest the resulting PDF
     * @param pow the PDF will be N-upped with N = Math.pow(2, pow);
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest, int pow)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // reader for the src file
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        // initializations
        Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(1);
        Rectangle newSize = (pow % 2) == 0 ?
            new Rectangle(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight()) :
            new Rectangle(pageSize.getHeight(), pageSize.getWidth());
        Rectangle unitSize = new Rectangle(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
        for(int i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
            unitSize = new Rectangle(unitSize.getHeight() / 2, unitSize.getWidth());
        }
        int n = (int) Math.pow(2, pow);
        int r = (int) Math.pow(2, pow / 2);
        int c = n / r;
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document(newSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(String.format(dest, n)));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfImportedPage page;
        Rectangle currentSize;
        float offsetX, offsetY, factor;
        int total = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for(int i = 0; i < total;) {
            if(i % n == 0) {
                document.newPage();
            }
            currentSize = reader.getPageSize(++i);
            factor = Math.min(
                unitSize.getWidth() / currentSize.getWidth(),
                unitSize.getHeight() / currentSize.getHeight());
            offsetX = unitSize.getWidth() * ((i % n) % c) + (unitSize.getWidth() - (currentSize.getWidth() * factor)) / 2f;
            offsetY = newSize.getHeight() - (unitSize.getHeight() * (((i % n) / c) + 1)) + (unitSize.getHeight() - (currentSize.getHeight() * factor)) / 2f;
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            cb.addTemplate(page, factor, 0, 0, factor, offsetX, offsetY);
        }
        // step 5
        document.close();
        reader.close();
    }
    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException, DocumentException, SQLException {
        Stationery.main(args);
        new NUpTool().manipulatePdf(Stationery.RESULT, RESULT, 1);
        new NUpTool().manipulatePdf(Stationery.RESULT, RESULT, 2);
        new NUpTool().manipulatePdf(Stationery.RESULT, RESULT, 3);
        new NUpTool().manipulatePdf(Stationery.RESULT, RESULT, 4);
    }
}
```

and i try to process  a pdf file about 700MB , and it almost take half an hour to write pdf data to harddisk (i think is "document.close()" take too long time), and my computer cup 
I5-2430 2.4G Memory 6GB ,harddisk 520G 7200 RPM  it's not too bad , so i want to ask is there anyway to do some Optimization to speed up the  itext write speed.

thanks a lot

Eric

Comment: How much memory do you allow the JVM to use while running the program? Consider allowing some more.

Answer (score 1):

Are you embedding a video in the PDF? ;)

I don't really have an idea, but this is too long for a comment. I can see the following possibilities:

- The real processing starts when you call `document.close()`, before that only some preparation gets done.
- The processing involves some random file access which scales vary badly. Try to put the documents into a ram disk ([/dev/shm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_UNIX_platforms)).
- The processing needs a few gigabytes memory and you forgot to [give it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566026/581205) to your process.

Anyway, find out more, e.g., if the task is CPU or disk bound.

Comment: 700 MB is a *suspiciously* large size for about any PDF. My bet is items such as fonts get needlessly copied for each page.

Comment: .. see the comment under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604124/large-pdf-generation-using-itext-taking-very-long-time

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, it's a crazy size. And I guess you're right with your guess (but as I've said, I don't really have an clue).